# I want to disable the Home, Tools and Explorer keys on the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

[image]

I want to disable the Home, Tools and Explorer keys on the keyboard. When I check from setting->keyboard->custom shortcuts, these keys are called Home, Tools and Explorer.
All combinations are disabled in the Settings section. What can I do?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Wayland or X11? what is the return of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` in terminal?